# Display or not a row with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am not a programmer but try to do my best with my own website. I have an online apparel store and I want to display on the item description just the values available for the item, now I have a table with some rows that I want to hide and compress the table if there is not a value for it. for example...

```
   <tr>
    <td style="width:30%"><b>· Hip:</b>  {{HIP}}</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%"><b>· Inseam:</b>  {{INSEAM}}</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%"><b>· Rise:</b>  {{RISE}}</td>

  </tr>
```

it should display...

```
· Hip: {{HIP}}
· Inseam: {{INSEAM}}
· Rise: {{RISE}}
```

I want that if I didn't have the "inseam" value on my inventory file this row will hide and just display...

```
· Hip: {{HIP}}
· Rise: {{RISE}}
```

I can not use javascript as eBay don't allow it. Sorry if I do not express myself in the right programming language. Hope someone can help me. Thanks to all!!!

Comment: You can't do it with just CSS, you can certainly hide a row by using display:none, but if you have to do it conditionally based on whether it is there in db or not, you need javascript

Comment: You can do it with CSS, see my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

With a little bit of refactoring your code and the :empty pseudoselector:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="hip" style="width:30%">{{HIP}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="inseam" style="width:30%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rise" style="width:30%">{{RISE}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.hip:before {
  content: '· Hip: ';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inseam:before {
  content: '· Inseam: ';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rise:before {
  content: '· Rise: ';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inseam:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fL1y0mg/2/

try adding {{INSEAM}} into that table row

Comment: That's ok, don't know why someone would vote this down anyway :)